# How to add .so files to java.library.path in node.js

Tags: node.js, .so, node-java

I am working with node.js by using node-java.
I need to add `libFaCTPlusPlusJNI.so` to java library path. 
Is there any chance to add the java library path in .js file ?

Thank you!

Comment: When loading the shared objet, you only specify the name less `lib`. In your case it will be `FaCTPlusPlusJNI.so`. `java.library.path` will then need to point to the directory containing the shared library.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My question was how to point the directory to `java.library.path` ? Is there any syntax in nodejs ?